# C++ Template specialization with variable template parameter count

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the problem, that i have a `template<typename R, typename... ArgTs>` class that should have a function `R call(ArgTs... args)`. The Problem is, that i need a special case, where R is void. I already tried `std::is_same<...>` with `constexpr` but this is not possible as i use c++11.

Here i have broken down the problem to the two functions and how i think it sould look like:

```
template <typename R, typename... ArgTs>
R call(Callable<R, ArgTs...> *_callback, SemaphoreHandle_t _mutex, ArgTs... args) {
    xSemaphoreTakeRecursive(_mutex, portMAX_DELAY);

    if (_callback != nullptr) {
        if (_callback->isAlive()) {
            R returnVal = _callback->call(args...);
            xSemaphoreGiveRecursive(_mutex);
            return returnVal;
        }
    }

    xSemaphoreGiveRecursive(_mutex);
    return (R)0;
}

template <typename... ArgTs>
void call<void, ArgTs...>(Callable<void, ArgTs...> *_callback, SemaphoreHandle_t _mutex,
                        ArgTs... args) {
    xSemaphoreTakeRecursive(_mutex, portMAX_DELAY);

    if (_callback != nullptr) {
        if (_callback->isAlive()) {
            _callback->call(args...);
        }
    }

    xSemaphoreGiveRecursive(_mutex);
}
```

The compiler gives this error: `error: non-type partial specialization 'call<void, ArgTs ...>' is not allowed`

I understand why, as the two templates are basically the same, as they accept as many parameters as you want, but how can i solve this problem?

The function should also be inside of a class as method (`template class ...`), but with the two functions i wrote i could build only a wrapper inside the class to make the template thing simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function templates can't be partial specified, you can overload them.

```
template <typename R, typename... ArgTs>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<R, void>::value, R>::type 
call(Callable<R, ArgTs...> *_callback, SemaphoreHandle_t _mutex, ArgTs... args) {
    ...
}

template <typename... ArgTs>
void
call(Callable<void, ArgTs...> *_callback, SemaphoreHandle_t _mutex, ArgTs... args) {
    ...
}
```

Or if you still need the template parameter `R` for the 2nd function template, you can add the `std::enable_if` check for it too.

```
template <typename R, typename... ArgTs>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<R, void>::value, R>::type 
call(Callable<R, ArgTs...> *_callback, SemaphoreHandle_t _mutex, ArgTs... args) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much! This was exactly what i searched for, but i had to add this to the second function:

```template <typename R, typename... ArgTs>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<R, void>::value, R>::type call(...```

Comment: @T.M. Fine, added to my answer.